# dyamically constructing javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, chart.js

i'm trying to dynamically populate a javascript object with data i have fetched from an api (pivotal tracker).

i have a javascript object called 'results' which looks like this:

```
   [ {"state"=>"finished",
  "range"=>"6 months",
  "points"=>0,
  "numberStories"=>0,
  "points / story"=>"N/A"},
 {"state"=>"finished",
  "range"=>"9 months",
  "points"=>0,
  "numberStories"=>0,
  "points / story"=>"N/A"},
 {"state"=>"finished",
  "range"=>"12 months",
  "points"=>0,
  "numberStories"=>0,
  "points / story"=>"N/A"}]
```

and i'm trying to write the javascript which will dynamically populate the chartjs object so that i graph one line for each 'state' showing number of 'points' for each 'range.

the chartjs object (with dummy data) looks like this:

```
var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}
```

what i have tried so far is:

```
var data ={};   
var data["labels"] = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
    data["labels"].push(results[i]["range"]);
}
```

its obvious that i haven't initialised the array inside data properly, but i can't quite figure out how this should be done.   the same will apply to datasets, when i get there.... any pointers?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I followed your question. Here is some commented code:

```
var set = [
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}];

// Initialize data object
var data = { labels:[], datasets:[] };

// Get the distinct list of labels (range).
// * Done in a separate step to get a known count
// * of labels for initializing the datasets
data.labels = set.reduce(function(memo,el){
    if (memo.indexOf(el.range) === -1)
        memo.push(el.range);

    return memo;
},[]);

// Get a distinct list of datasets (states)
var _sets = set.reduce(function(memo,el){
    if (memo.indexOf(el.state) === -1){
        memo.push(el.state);

        // create a dataset record at the same index as 
        // the matching state. 
        // Initiatize the data collection for each label
        data.datasets.push({
            data:data.labels.map(function(){ return 0 }),
            name:el.state,
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff"
        });

    }
    return memo;
},[]);

// Go through the set and assign points to the 
// appropriate data bucket
set.map(function(el){
    var setIdx = _sets.indexOf(el.state);
    var labelIdx = data.labels.indexOf(el.range);

    data.datasets[setIdx].data[labelIdx] += el.points;
},[]);

console.log(data);
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xP56/

Comment: amazingly quick and accurate response that taught me a fair bit.... once i managed to get my head round it.  many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`results` was not an array (missing `[]`) perhaps that was the problem?

```
var results = [{
"state": "finished",
"range":"6 months",
"points":0,
"numberStories":0,
"points / story":"N/A"
},
{
"state":"finished",
"range":"9 months",
"points":0,
"numberStories":0,
"points / story":"N/A"
},
{
"state":"finished",
"range":"12 months",
"points":0,
"numberStories":0,
"points / story":"N/A"}
];

var data = {
        labels: []
    };   


for (var i = 0 ; i < results.length ; i++) {
    data.labels.push(results[i].range);
}

alert(data.labels.length);
```

Otherwise, this should work I think?

Also note that you first define `data` and then later on redefine it. (But that's probably on purpose for the example?)

Note that if you know its name, you can access a property directly with `.range` (instead of `["range"]`)

Comment: 'results' was an array that i copied from terminal. have added the square brackets to clarify. the literal notation for instantiating labels[] was the hint i needed. and thanks for the tip on accessing proprties...still stuck in my ruby ways to a certain extent